# move_uploaded_file - max file size issue

Tags: php, upload, size

I'm trying to upload a file on my server with PHP,
But it fails :

`move_uploaded_file()` returns false.

My file is a text file of 230,000 chars (224 ko)

However, if I try to reduce the file to 4500 chars, It works well.

Is there a maximum of the number of character ?

```
<?php

$host="";
$user="";
$pass="";
//$db = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
//mysql_select_db('paul_biaudet',$db);
$dossier = 'update-';

$fichier = basename($_FILES['avatar']['name']);

$taille_maxi = 100000;
$taille = filesize($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
$extensions = array('.txt','.doc');
$extension = strrchr($_FILES['avatar']['name'], '.'); 
//security
if(!in_array($extension, $extensions)) 
{
     $erreur = 'Vous devez uploader un fichier texte';
}
if($taille>$taille_maxi)
{
     $erreur = 'too big';
}
if($_FILES['avatar']['name']!='shapes.txt' && $_FILES['avatar']['name']!='routes.txt' ){
    $erreur='...';
}
if(!isset($erreur)) //no error :  upload
{

     $fichier = strtr($fichier, 
          'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 
          'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
     $fichier = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $fichier);
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier)) 
     {
     ...
    }
else 
 {
      echo 'fail';
 }
```

And .... it's a fail

Comment: Have you tried with other files? Maybe your site has a max_upload_size for files.

Comment: Other files works well as soon as they contains few character :/

Comment: Then check (as the answer say) the max_upload_size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 4):

Check your html code for a MAX_FILE_SIZE e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
```

Check your upload-max-filesize and post-max-size
See:
http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

and

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

What is the result for:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('upload-max-filesize'),'<br />'
,ini_get('post-max-size'),'<br />';
?>
```

**Edit**

> upload_max_filesize = 2M and post_max_size = 8M

Strange...
Try to make an upload with:

```
ini_set('upload-max-filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
```

Comment: If you don't mention, how to change those values, then your answer is not really an answer.

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 2M and post_max_size = 8M

Comment: It's not a matter of size of my file I think, it's only 224ko :/ The ini_set doesn't work, but 2 Mo should be enough

Comment: I'm really sorry, the error is in the the "form" in the HTML :   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">  Apologize for my ctrl-c / ctrl-v  ...